# How to remove index.html from url in S3 website hosting?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a directory like this:

```
/example.com/
  index.html
    foo/
      index.html
```

The index document is set to `index.html`, so when the url is `https://example.com`, it shows `/example.com/index.html`.

Also, I wanna show `/example.com/foo/index.html` when the url is `https://example.com/foo` .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you have activated [Static Website Hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html) on your S3 bucket, and have configured `index.html` as your default page, this will work automatically.

[image: Static website hosting]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/images/staticwebsitehosting20.png))</sub>

To test this, I did the following:

- Created a new bucket
- Turned on Static Website hosting
- Created a `foo` directory
- Uploaded an `index.html` file to the `foo` directory and made it public
- Copied the bucket URL from the Static Website Hosting page and appended `/foo`

It looked like:

```
http://my-bucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/foo
```

The index page came up just fine.

By the way, it redirected me to `/foo/`.

Comment: I wanna redirect 'https://example.com' to '/example.com/index.html', and 'https://example.com/foo' to '/example.com/foo/index.html' at the same time

Comment: That's what this does, @Taichi.